# Why in Spring Security I need the intercept-url?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am studying Spring Security and I have a doubt related its configuration.

So I know that into the Spring configuration file I need to have something like this:

```
<beans>
    <security:http>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/accounts/**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY" />
        <security:form-login login-page="/login.htm"/>
        <security:logout logout-success-url="/index.html"/>
    </security:http>
</beans>
```

So my doubt is: Why I need the intercept-url? Is it only related to specify what specific URL I need to make secure? Can you give me more precise information?

Tnx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, with intercept-url you specify the urls which have to be secured, and also the type of the access (like the role which is necessary etc.). You can find more about this in the documentation: http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/el-access.html